# TypeError: u.indexOf is not a function for Reactjs and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, styled-components

I am running into the following Error while following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QiTq5WrWoJw&t=8176s

I am having issues connecting my individual messages into my firebase application. My error in the console focuses on the following code.

I am trying to send a message within in an indvidiual "room" within firebase so a collection of rooms with unique messages within each room.

```
function ChatInput(channelName, channelId) {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const sendMessage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevents refresh of the page

        if(!channelId) {
            return false;
        }
            db.collection("rooms").doc(channelId).collection("messages").add({
              message: input,
              timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              user: 'Daniel Peters',
              userImage:'https://wallpapercave.com/wp/j8Sd6Uv.jpg',

            });

            setInput('');
    };

    return (
        <ChatInputContainer>
            <form>
                <input value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} placeholder= {`Message #${channelName}`} />
                <Button hidden type='submit' onClick={sendMessage}>
                    SEND
                </Button>
            </form>



        </ChatInputContainer>
    )
}

export default ChatInput;
```

I have tried different version of redux and firebase to see if that was the issue, however the issue is obviously not resolved. Any guidance would be great!

Comment: Have you written `something.indexOf...` anywhere in code?

Comment: Out of my whole code the only thing that has ".index" is in my serviceWorker.js, nothing that I have written that was wasn't a dependency.

Answer (score 19):

I just faced this issue and eventually my "mistake" Was that I was trying to use numeric ids as firestore document keys.

So this one gave that `u.indexOf is not a function` error:

```
      let ref = db.collection(`userPreferences/${userId}/venues`).doc(venue.id);
```

Where as this one worked:

```
  let ref = db.collection(`userPreferences/${userId}/venues`).doc(`${venue.id}`);
```

I just surrounded the second one in quotes to make it a string.
Hope that saves someone's day!

Comment: Indeed it did! Had the same issue with angular fire. Solved by using the back ticks. +1

Comment: Thanks! you're a life saver! I was trying to store id as Date.now() timestamp but it was a number so i did using Date.now().toString()  and it stored it. I wish the error message was more precise

Comment: this saved my day. I have been debugging for 2 hours.

Comment: Saved my day!  You are a hero to the people!! 

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this error by changing my key name from a number to a string:

```
export const addRecord = async () => {
    for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        const keyName = i + '' // converting the number to a string is the solution!
        await setDoc(doc(db, "names", keyName), {
            name: "hello world",
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case Make the channelId string and then pass to doc()

Just like:

```
function ChatInput(channelName, channelId) {

const [input, setInput] = useState('');

const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents refresh of the page

    if(!channelId) {
        return false;
    }
        db.collection("rooms").doc(`${channelId}`).collection("messages").add({
          message: input,
          timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          user: 'Daniel Peters',
          userImage:'https://wallpapercave.com/wp/j8Sd6Uv.jpg',

        });

        setInput('');
};

return (
    <ChatInputContainer>
        <form>
            <input value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} placeholder= {`Message #${channelName}`} />
            <Button hidden type='submit' onClick={sendMessage}>
                SEND
            </Button>
        </form>



    </ChatInputContainer>
)
```

}

export default ChatInput;

Answer (score 0):

I Have faced this error and after a long time finally fixed it, just like this

change this :

```
useEffect(() => {
  onSnapshot(
   doc(db, 'users', `${user?.email}`, (doc) => {
     setMovies(doc.data()?.savedShows);
   })
  );
}, [user?.email]);
```

to this :

```
useEffect(() => {
  onSnapshot(doc(db, 'users', `${user?.email}`), (doc) => {
   setMovies(doc.data()?.savedShows);
  });
 }, [user?.email]);
```